# *args in BigQuery Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

Is there any concept of `*args` in BigQuery parameters (similar to pytho *args)

I am writing a generic stored procedure that will check if the table has duplicate rows. Obviously the number of columns will vary & given at the run time.

So I want to use `*args` to receive arguments, unpack them & use them in dynamic SQL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `my_project.LOGGING.check_dup_prc`(project_name STRING, data_set_name STRING, table_name STRING, date_id DATE, *args)
BEGIN
  DECLARE sql STRING;
  set sql ='Select date,*args,count(1) from `'||project_name||'.'||data_set_name||'.'||table_name|| '` where date=\''||date_id || '\' GROUP BY date,*args HAVING COUNT(*)>1';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (sql);
END;
```

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: provide simplified example of how you expect this to work

Comment: So here is what I am trying to achieve. The below-stored procedure has col1-col4 which I want to make *args i.e. user can specify one or more columns. 
The stored procedure should be able to unpack *args aka col1,col2,col3 ... etc. & inject them into dynamic SQL

Comment: --stored procedure
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `my_project.LOGGING.check_dup_prc`(project_name STRING, data_set_name STRING, table_name STRING, date_id DATE, col1 STRING,col2 STRING,col3 STRING, col4 STRING)
BEGIN
  DECLARE sql STRING;
  set sql ='Select date,'||col1||','||col2||','||col3||','||col4||','||'count(1) from `'||project_name||'.'||data_set_name||'.'||table_name|| '` where date=\''||date_id || '\' GROUP BY date,'||col1||','||col2||','||col3||','||col4||'HAVING COUNT(*)>1';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (sql);
END;

Comment: -- Call the stored procedure 
CALL `my_project.LOGGING.check_dup_prc`(my_project, my_project,my_table,CURRENT_DATE(),col1,col2,col3,col4);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to be able to pass to proc list of the columns that will be used in SELECT as well as GROUP BY. In this case, instead of passing list of separate dolumns you can just pas one parameter which will hold list of those columns as a one string  as in below example

So, it will be like below (the rest of syntax is left as it is in the question)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE my_project.LOGGING.check_dup_prc(project_name STRING, data_set_name STRING, table_name STRING, date_id DATE, cols STRING) 
BEGIN DECLARE sql STRING; 
set sql ='Select date,'||cols||','||'count(1) from '||project_name||'.'||data_set_name||'.'||table_name|| ' where date=\''||date_id || '\' GROUP BY date,'||cols||'HAVING COUNT(*)>1'; 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (sql); END;
```

and call will look like below

```
CALL my_project.LOGGING.check_dup_prc(my_project, my_project,my_table,CURRENT_DATE(),'col1,col2,col3,col4');
```